# reportlab doc.build(story) how to change output directory using asksaveasfilename tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, tkinter, save, reportlab

I use reportlab lyibrary while creating tkinter app on Python. Method `doc.build(story)` saves PDF-file to current directory. But I want to push the button and save this file to the chosen directory by myself via asksaveasfilename of tkinter. How can I do that?

```
def save_as_pdf(self, file_path=None):
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('DejaVuSerif', 'DejaVuSerif.ttf'))
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(f"{self.current_friend}_computers.pdf", pagesize=letter)
        story = []


        data= [self.table_computers.item(row_id)['values'] for row_id in self.table_computers.get_children()]
        
        tblstyle = TableStyle([('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, len(data)-1), 'DejaVuSerif', 12)])
        tbl = Table(data)
        tbl.setStyle(tblstyle)
        story.append(tbl)
        if file_path is None:
            file_path = asksaveasfilename(
                filetypes=(
                    ("PDF-файл", "*.pdf"),
                    ("All files", "*.*"),
                ),
                initialfile=(f"{self.current_friend}_computers.pdf"),
            )
        print(file_path)
        doc.build(story)
```

As I said, method `doc.build(story)` saves PDF-file to current directory. I want to save in another

I tried to find a file path command inside of build method. But it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the decision

```
def save_as_pdf(self, file_path=None):
    pdf_file =BytesIO()
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('DejaVuSerif', 'DejaVuSerif.ttf'))
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_file, pagesize=letter)
    story = []
    

    data= [self.table_computers.item(row_id)['values'] for row_id in self.table_computers.get_children()]
    
    data.append([f'У вашего друга {self.current_friend} следующие компьютеры: '])
    data.reverse()
    
    tblstyle = TableStyle([('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, len(data)-1), 'DejaVuSerif', 12)])
    tbl = Table(data)
    tbl.setStyle(tblstyle)
    story.append(tbl)
    if file_path is None:
        file_path = asksaveasfilename(
            filetypes=(
                ("PDF-файл", "*.pdf"),
                ("All files", "*.*"),
            ),
            initialfile=(f"{self.current_friend}_computers.pdf"),
        )
    doc.build(story)
    pdf_file.seek(0)
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(pdf_file.getbuffer())
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**